# Inheritance of operator()

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I am stumped by why the declaration of `void operator()(int)` in the base class in the code sample below is seemingly hidden when the derived class implements `void operator()(int,int,int)`. How can I get the declaration of operator()(int) from the base class `foo` to be visible in the derived class `bar`? That is, how can I modify the example so that the invocation of operator()(int) works?

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
        void operator()(int)
        {
                std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        }
};

struct bar : foo
{
        // If this is uncommented, the code will not compile.
        // void operator()(int, int, int) {}
};

int main()
{
        bar b;
        b(1);
        return 0;
}
```

When compiled with g++ with the marked lines uncommented, the error message is along the lines of "no match for call to 'bar (int)' ... candidate is void bar::operator()(int,int,int) ... candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's right.  Derived class functions hide base class functions rather than overloading.  The fix is pretty simple though:

```
struct bar : foo
{
     using foo::operator();
     void operator()(int, int, int) {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please explain why the using declaration is necessary in this case? I don't see how declaring operator()(int,int,int) should eclipse the declaration of operator()(int) in the base class. Having to specify the using keyword is a little cumbersome, since in a real-world scenario, I'd have to add this to every base class.

Comment: Why?  Because the standard says so.  "A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region or derived class."  See also: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#overloadderived

Comment: Actually, overrides of virtual functions also hide base class functions. This is especially annoying when a base class has multiple public virtual functions which are overloads of the same name: when overriding just one of them all of the others are hidden! This is one of the reasons why the standard C++ library doesn't have any public virtual functions (except for destructors which can't be overloaded anyway and work somewhat different with respect to overriding anyway). Instead, public function delegate to the protected (they should really be private) virtual functions.

Comment: This is a little irritating, especially because I cannot declare a global operator() to avoid having to specify the using declaration in every base class.

Comment: Should be `using foo::operator();`?

Comment: This seems like a bad design choice in the C++ specification.  It breaks polymorphism.

Comment: @UncleBens: Using declarations can either pull in an overloaded name, or a specific overload.  Possibly the return type (`void`) is needed when mentioning a specific overload.

Comment: @japreiss: No it doesn't.  You can pass a `bar` to a function taking `foo&`, and that function will find the one-argument version no problem.

Comment: @UncleBens: On reading the standard, I think you're right.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Note that operator() might make this look more confusing than it is. The classic example would probably be something more like bar::mymethod(int) and foo::mymethod(). The derived method hides the inherited method because of how resolution happens. The using declaration explained in another answer brings in foo's method for resolution.